# docs list api v2 v. v3

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I can find the API call required to insert a meta-data-only file at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/v2/developers_guide_protocol, bu this is v2. The equivalent page for v3 doesn't show the equivalent information.

Anybody know if this changed from v2 to v3, or is it the same format?

```
POST /feeds/folders/private/full/folder%3Afolder_id HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
Authorization: <your authorization header here>
Content-Length: 292
Content-Type: application/atom+xml

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
      term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#presentation" label="presentation"/>
  <atom:title>new preso</atom:title>
</atom:entry>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for creating documents with metadata only (v3) is here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_a_new_document_or_file_with_metadata_only

The only differences I see are:

- You should use the `resumable-create-media` link that you can get from the feed
- You should set the header

  ```
  X-Upload-Content-Length: 0
  ```

Comment: I'd found that, but was looking for the Javascript/http definition. Are you saying that simply by setting X-Upload-Content-Length: 0, it becomes a meta-data only insert?

Comment: If you click on `Protocol` (beside `.NET`) in the example, you should see the HTTP version. And I think that adding that header should be enough.

Answer (score -1):

That version is deprecated. Use the Drive SK. Does this [page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) solve your issue? They have a playground to try out the methods.

Comment: Sadly the Drive SDK has too many unresolved bugs. The gdata feeds are more mature, and so hopefully more reliable. Given the v3 docslist API is supported until 2015, I'll run with that until the Drive SDK is reliable.